# Make/Convert list of text into block of text

Tags: sed, scripting, archlinux

I would like to take a text-file containing a list of installed packages, each on a separate line, and join them into a single line. My current shell-script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i '1 i\sudo pacman -Syu' pkglist.txt
sed -i 's/$/ /' pkglist.txt
```

And my `pkglist.txt` file looks a like this:

```
sudo pacman -Syu  
accountsservice 
adobe-source-han-sans-cn-fonts 
adobe-source-han-sans-jp-fonts 
adobe-source-han-sans-kr-fonts 
adobe-source-sans-fonts 
aic94xx-firmware 
...
```

My desired final look of `pkglist.txt` is something like this:

```
sudo pacman -Syu accountsservice adobe-source-han-sans-cn-fonts adobe-source-han-sans-jp-fonts adobe-source-han-sans-kr-fonts adobe-source-sans-fonts aic94xx-firmware ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest with `bash`:

```
sudo pacman -Syu $(paste -s pkglist.txt)
```

I assume `sudo pacman -Syu` is not part of `pkglist.txt` and no file name contains spaces or tabs.

Answer (score 0):

xargs sudo pacman -Syu < pkglist.txt

This should do as you wish. No need to modify pkglist.txt to add the sudo packman at the start.